# ACF repeater field not updating

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've register my repeater field using PHP and when i try to used the update_field function it save the whole array in one field only.

here is my code:

```
$imgArr = array();
$pid = 241;
foreach( $images as $image ){
    $imgArr [] = array( 'image_url'=> $image );
}
update_field( 'property_listing_images', $imgArr , $pid );
```

and here  is result in my database:
[result in the database when I try updating my repeater field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJCrp.jpg)
is there any other way to update the fields in repeater field?

Comment: Have you tried using the `update_sub_field` function? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_sub_field/

Comment: @frederikvdbe: I've tried it and still no luck

$imgArr = array();
$pid = 241;
$i = 1;
foreach( $images as $image ){
   update_sub_field( array('property_listing_images', $i, 'image_url'), $l_image );
   i++;
}